# Time delay of LPF to exponential decay amplitude input

Tags: filters, analog

How can one calculate the time delay a Low Pass analog filter adds from steady state when the amplitude of the input signal decays exponentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't: time delay would be calculated through *group delay*, and in general, that's different for different frequencies. Your input doesn't contain only a single frequency, so it will come out *dispersed*.

There's an exception to that rule: Linear-phase filters have *constant group delay* over all frequencies. That's because the group delay is the negative derivative of the phase over frequency, and if the phase is linear with frequency, the derivative is a constant.

Only FIR filter that are time-symmetric can be linear phase. And the group delay of these, assuming they're applied in a causal fashion (without a leading lag), is always half the filter length.

Sadly, analog filters (i.e. such that are continuous in time) *cannot* be linear in phase, so that you will always have a non-constant group delay, and can't say "this exponential was delayed by an additional time $\tau$", because you simply don't get a scaled exponential as an output.

Comment: You can make analog transversal filters (switched capacitor filters, SAW filters etc) and those can have linear phase for the same reason, right?

Comment: Switched Capacitor: heh, that's discrete-time! SAW: Don't think you can *actually* get linear phase in those, but they might be linear enough... haven't thought about their phase, to be honest.